# How to reference a secret from Key Vault in VSTS build step

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create a build task that will deploy an ARM template and use a secret from Key Vault as a password for SQL server (PaaS logic server). I've linked a secret1 in the Variable Groups and trying to Override Template Parameters with `-sqlAdministratorLoginPassword $(secret1)` but my build tasks fails with the following error:

> Cannot bind parameter 'sqlAdministratorLoginPassword'. Cannot convert
>   the "********" value of type "System.String" to type
>   "System.Security.SecureString".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that you linked azure key vault to build definition. How about reference key vault in ARM directly? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter

Comment: On the other hand, try to convert to SecureString through PowerShell `task param(
[string]$p
)
$pSecure=ConvertTo-SecureString $(p) -AsPlainText -Force
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myPassword;issecret=true;]$pSecure"` Arguments: `-p $(secret1)`, then specify Template Parameters to `-sqlAdministratorLoginPassword $(myPassword)`.

Comment: BTW, the secret value will be decrypted during build (build task, but can't output as general variable), that's why it throws can't convert to SecureString.

Comment: I'm not OK with referencing key vault in ARM directly, since I need to specify different Key Vaults and secrets for different environments (dev, qa, staging...) and going into ARM template to do that is not something I'd want. I'd like to specify them with VSTS. I'm not sure how to do what you described. I need to create a PowerShell build step before Azure Resource Group Deployment step? I'd rather don't do it, but if that's the only way to do that... I followed this article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/variable-groups to the letter and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, try to add a PowerShell task before Azure Resource Group Deployment task and check the result.

Comment: I tried pasting your script into "PowerShell++" task https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxEMk.png and recieved the following errors:
https://pastebin.com/wMdyRm4h
I tried creating .ps1 file and running it with "PowerShell Script" task  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzd7s.png with no arguments and received the following error:
https://pastebin.com/ukZvQBFq

Comment: What's your detail code? You need to specify the argument.

Comment: What do you mean by detail code? I don't know what to put into "arguments". Could you help, please?

Comment: The code in VSTSconvertToSecureString.ps1.

Comment: It is: task param( [string]$p ) $pSecure=ConvertTo-SecureString $(p) -AsPlainText -Force Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myPassword;issecret=true;]$pSecure" Arguments: -p $(secret1), then specify Template Parameters to -sqlAdministratorLoginPassword $(myPassword)

Comment: The script should be `param( [string]$p ) $pSecure=ConvertTo-SecureString $(p) -AsPlainText -Force Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myPassword;issecret=true;]$pSecure"`

Comment: And specify the arguments of PowerShell task: `-p $(secret1)` (secret1 is the build variable)

Comment: Check this screenshot: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AresBGZVYryjhTbdHprW-Sn52Kau

Comment: Doesn't work. `p : The term 'p' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEwEo.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksQJm.png

Comment: Each code statement need to be in the new line, check my screenshot.

Comment: So, I've decided not to use this approach and went with Reference a secret with dynamic ID https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter I don't understand why this article gives instructions to not working solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/variable-groups

Comment: Because the values are retrieved as strings. Has the issue been solved withe the reference a secret with dynamic ID? If so, you can post an answer.

Comment: We ended up ditching the solution.